# System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, .net-5

I am getting the below error in production mode. its running fine in localhost as well in test bench.

> 2/10/2022 9:53:06 AM :GetList : System.PlatformNotSupportedException:
> Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
> at LiveImpexUI.DL.VariantsInfo.GetList(IConfiguration _iconfig, String
> contentPath) in C:\Personal
> Storage\DeepakJha\LiveImpex\WIP\1.0\LiveImpexUI\LiveImpexUI\DL\VariantsInfo.cs:line
> 29

First I was using `system.data.SqlClient`. Then I shifted to `microsoft.data.SqlClient`

The below image is `.csproj`

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="6.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="6.2.3" />   </ItemGroup>
```

And the production server is running on Windows.

I have tried different solution on internet. Please help!

Comment: I have to ask: if you're using MySQL, why are you using the MSSQL driver (i.e. a completely different database software)? Note that both `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and `System.Data.SqlClient` are designed for use with MSSQL, not MySQL.

Comment: sorry my bad, i am using MSSQL not MySQL

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: The error seems self explanatory... "Platform Not Supported" - you must be running it on an unsupported platform.

Comment: @DaleK. Sorry i was not aware about guideline. this is the first time i  am posting something.

Comment: it's running proper on test bench but not in production. can you explain or give some hints about that , why it's behaving like this

Comment: I did, its not supported on your platform... given we don't know anything about your platform there is nothing more we can do. And you haven't yet replaced the image with the code.

Comment: I solved the issue by configuring the app to only run with admin rights!